# How to use modulo 10^9+7

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to write a code for **sum of square of natural numbers** but with mod it's giving wrong answer. What would be the correct way here?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    cout<< (((N) * (N+1) * (2*N+1))/6)%mod;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: your formula corresponds to the sum of the squares of the natural numbers.

Comment: @Ronald `(N) * (N+1) * (2*N+1)` is (when working with natural numbers, without overflow) always divisible by 6.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @Damien i have made the change in question. Also, I would like to point out that N is a big number typically in the long long range. I was asked to calculate the sum and return it in `int` return format after doing modulo.

Comment: @harold I don't know what made me think that the expression isn't divisible by 6, but you are right. I apologize for the false alert

Comment: Related: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @Stef Not related but sure i know why we should not use `<bits/stdc++.h>`, but in terms of competitive programming, it's a great thing to have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(N) * (N+1) * (2*N+1)` can be, even if `N` is less than 1000000007, too large. Namely up to 2000000039000000253000000546, which is an 91-bit number. It is not likely that `int` on your system is capable of containing such large numbers.

As usual with this type of question, the work-around is a combination of:

- Using a larger integer type for intermediate products, *and*
- Applying modulo reduction on intermediate products, not only at the end.

Using just one of them is not sufficient.

As a consequence of applying modulo reduction earlier, the division by 6 will not work with a normal division, it will have to be a multiplication by the modular multiplicative inverse of 6 mod 1000000007, which is 166666668.

Example code:

```
mod_mul(mod_mul(mod_mul(N, N + 1, mod), mod_mul(2, N, mod) + 1, mod), inv6, mod)
```

Using some suitable definition of `mod_mul`, which can avoid overflow by using `long long` or a similar type.

Comment: Don't we need mod on N and N+1 as well? like `N%mod` and `(N+1)%mod`. N is large enough to go over any data type range when multiplied with itself

Comment: @SumitJaiswal you can do that, but it seems like overkill to me. `mod_mul` should be able to handle numbers slightly above `mod` as well, as long as they fit in an `int`. If `N+1` could overflow an `int`, that would be an issue that could be avoided by applying `N %= mod`.

Comment: I guess i was missing that `inv6` for multplication instead of division, and also didn't think about `2*N` it can overflow as well thanx for the help.